# how to convert one line containing several sentences into lines according to dot(.)

Tags: java, string

The question might look confusing. Here I explain it.
I have a single line in a file containing

```
 "This is the line. containing several sentences .and it is not well formatted."
```

I want this in sentences according to `"."` as

```
This is the line.
containing several sentences.
and it is not well formatted.
```

I have tried using

```
 String line = "This is the line. containing several sentences .and it is not well formatted.";
   String[] lineArr = line.split(".");
        for(String sentence:lineArr){
            System.out.println(""+sentence);
        }
    }
```

My idea is to removing the spaces before and after `"."` and then applying split().
How should I achieve this?

Comment: So how exactly doesn't this work? Include what you are getting and how this differs from what you want.

Comment: I do not have an idea how to remove spaces before and after a ".". Though I have used mystring.replaceAll("\\s+(?=[.])", ""). It did not worked.

Comment: Use this regex: `"\\s*\\.\\s*"`. You can also `.trim()` your sentences.

Comment: You need to start reading documentation of methods you are using. `split` is using regex as argument and in regex `.` has special meaning. It can represent any character (except line separators). To make regex treat it as literal you need to escape it (prefferebly as `split("\\.")`). Also remember that `split` removes delimiters, so you may need to add them in your print statement, or use look-behind `(?<=\\.)` as split parameter.

Comment: Why duplicate? The question "Split String on dot . as delimiter" is different from what I have asked. It does not remove the spaces.

Comment: But Thanks for your explanation about the question

Comment: "Why duplicate?" Because your code example shows that main problem is lack of escaping of dot (unless you posted wrong example) which is explained in duplicate question. I believe that with this information you will be able to solve your problem now (for instance with simple `trim()` method).

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks. Now I have the idea how to solve it.